# How to use OrTools in Java (Spring Boot)

Tags: or-tools

I'm struggling to add OrTools to our Spring Boot project, basically what I've done is first try to add the dependency using gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.ortools:ortools-java:9.2.9972'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.19.4'
```

But when using the `CpModel` we have an error on Protobuf even if it is downloaded by gradle:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder
```

So I tried to load the dependency using the OrTools Loader:

```
Loader.loadNativeLibraries();
```

And Here I have another error and can't find the solution:

```
Resource ortools-darwin-aarch64/ was not found in ClassLoader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32
```

Do you have any idea? Is there someone that has a working OrTools with spring?

(I'm on MacOS arm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or-tools is a C++ library wrapped in java using swig. currently we only provide/support amd64 cpu arch and LInux/MacOS and windows platform.

I'll try to add a Java M1 issue but since we still don't have any M1 for testing and dev, don't expect support soon ;)

ps: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues?q=apple+m1+

Comment: Got it, thanks for this quick answer!